# Pytorch add hyperparameters for 3x3,32 conv2d layer and 2x2 maxpool layer

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, hyperparameters

I am trying to create a conv2d layer below using pytorch. The hyperparameters are given in the image below. I am unsure how to implement the hyperparameters (3x3,32) for the first conv2d layer. I want to know how to use this using `torch.nn.Conv2d`.
Thank you very much.

[Conv2d with hyperparameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qyLG.png)

Answer (score 0):

The conv2d hyper-parameters (`3`x`3`, `32`) represents `kernel_size=(3, 3)` and number of output channels=32.
Therefore, this is how you define the first conv layer in your diagram:

```py
conv3x3_32 = nn.Conv2d(in_channles=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)
```

Note that the `in_channles` hyper-parameter should match the `out_channels` of the previous layer (or the input's).

For more details, see [`nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html#torch.nn.Conv2d).

Comment: So if the `3x3` represents `kernel_size=(3,3)` why is `kernel_size=3` for the first layer?

Comment: @J.doe please **READ** the documentation, it's all there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just to clarify. 
The second layer should be 
`conv1x1_32 = nn.Conv2d(in_channles=32, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(1,1))`
right?

Comment: @J.doe yes - `in_channels` is derived from the `out_channels` of the previous layer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just want to clarify one last thing.
Whether the maxpool layer used here is correct.
`torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2))`
Thank you very much

Comment: @J.doe you'll need to add `stride=2` to the max pool layer.

Comment: So while keeping the same `kernel_size=(2,2)` I have to set the stride to`stride=2`?